# Bounding a sequence defined by the series to show its Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any way I can bound this series for fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Sequence is $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$ and I assumed here WLOG $n<m$ and let $m=n+k$ for some $k$.

$|\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k} \frac{x^i}{i!}| \leq |\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}|+...+|\frac{x^{n+k}}{(n+k)!}| \leq ...$

Does anyone have an idea? I'm trying to show that it's Cauchy so I want to show that series is smaller than for any $\epsilon >0$ by choosing $N>0$.

I have no idea how to bound this by. Please help!! thanks!!!

The series itself kind of looks like the exponential for Taylor expansion but I'm not sure if that'll come in help here.. :(

Comment: If you are trying to show it converges, can't you just use the ratio test?

Comment: yes, but the question asks me to show that its cauchy :( do you think i can bound the series using the ratio test is that possible?

Comment: Your choice of $n$ should depend on $x$.  Go out far enough so that the terms are decreasing, and then compare to geometric series.  (Same technique as ratio test, really.)

Comment: Does this make any sense? Since $i \to \infty$ using the ratio test $\frac{x}{i+1} \to 0$ which is $< \epsilon$ because $\epsilon >0$. Does this make any sense? Because it's really $n \to \infty$ but our series index $i$ depends on $n$ and $n$ goes to infinity.Ahh nevermind it doesnt make any sense.

Comment: What do you mean my choice of $n$ should depend on $x$ could you say a alittle more? I'm not getting it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose an integer $N$ such that $N > (2|x|)^{2}$. For $k >2(N-1)$ we have $\frac {|x|^{k}} {k!} < \frac {|x|^{k}} {N^{k-N+1}}$ because $k! >(1)(1)...(1)(N)(N)...(N)$ (where there are $(N-1)$ $1$'s). I leave it to you to show that $\frac {|x|^{k}} {N^{k-N+1}}< \frac 1 {2^{k}}$ for all $k >2(N-1)$. Finally use the fact that partial sums of $\sum \frac 1 {2^{k}}$ form a Cauchy sequence.  Hint: $1-\frac N k +\frac 1 k > \frac 1 2$.

Comment: Ohh yayyy I actually got it so happy now!! thanks so much!! if i may confirm a detail with you is $\frac{1}{(2|x|)^k} < \frac{1}{2^k}$ a true inequality? And could you explain how $\frac{|x|^k}{k!} < \frac{|x|^k}{n^{k-N+1}}$? i really don't understand how you got that.. :(

Comment: If you use the hint you will get $\frac {|x|^{k}} {N^{k-N+1}} <\frac {|x|^{k}} {(\sqrt N)^{k}}$. Also $\frac {|x|^{k}} {\sqrt N^{k}}< \frac 1 {2^{k}}$ by the choice of $N$.  For your second question write down the definition of $k!$ and note that the first $N-1$ factors are all greater than $1$ and the remaining factors are greater than $N$.

Comment: yess I got the inequality using your hint, thanks for your clarification!!! and i'm going to try to work the second question out now and could you please tell me why it is not required to show for all $k>0$? sorry for so many questions, thank you..

Comment: If you look at the definition of Cauchy sequence we are only interested in $a_n-a_m$ for large $n$ and $m$. Note that for $m>n$ the first $n$ terms of the series $\sum \frac {|x|^{k}} {k!}$ do not appear in $a_n-a_m$. So Cauchy property is not affected by the first few terms of the series.

Comment: thank you again i keep on asking stupid questions but, i'm still not quite sure how to arrive at the second inequality i tried writing down the definitions of $k!$ but didn't go anywhere $k!=k(k-1)(k-2)...2\cdot 1$ and $m=n+k$ which means $k=m-n$ so $(m-n)!=(m-n)(m-n-1)(m-n-2)...(m-n-n)(m-n-(n+1))(m-n-(n+2))...*3*2*1$

Comment: Take an example. Let $N=3$ and $k=7$. Do you agree that $7! \geq (1)(1)(3)(3)..(3)$ where there are $7-3+1=5$ threes?

Comment: yess i agree for the example but i can't see how it relates to it :( So, $k! >(1)(1)...(1)(N)(N)...(N)$ where there are $(N-1)$ $1$'s. So there are $k-N+1$ $N$'s. but why is there $k-N+1$ $N$'s? I think it has to do something to do with $k>2(N-1)$ but i can't see how it follows from $k>2(N-1)$ to saying there are $k-N+1$ $N$'s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94376/discussion-between-skypanties-and-kavi-rama-murthy).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with some fairly small $i$, we have $2^i < i!$, form then on, and forever:
$$
2^3 > 3!, \quad \mbox{ but } \quad
2^4 = 16, \; 4! = 24 \quad
2^5 = 32, \; 5! = 120 \quad, \ldots.
$$
Therefore, for $N \geq M \geq 4$,
$$
\sum_{i = M}^{N}{|x|^i \over i!} \leq \sum_{i = M}^{N}{|x|^i \over 2^i},
$$
and the latter series can be bounded by using the geometric series formula.

Comment: Wouldn't this only work for $|x|<2$?

Comment: thank you for the answer!! can i ask what the $N,M$ represent i can't really relate it between the notation of mine and yours :( and I don't think there is a "concrete" $N>0$ here but taking $N$ big large enough so that the inequality holds right?

Comment: Sorry, let me revise my notation a bit, and then I'll answer your question.

Comment: Ok.  My $M$ is your $n+1$, and my $N$ is your $n+k$.

Comment: In other words, I would be proving the Cauchy criterion for:

[ (the $N$-the partial sum) - (the $(M-1)$-th partial sum) ].